# Accessing file in network with Java

Tags: java, file, ftp, network-programming

I trying to access this file \192.168.1.1\d$\IISFolders\ftp\teste.png in my network to get his bytes and put in a json file and send.
But to access this directory I need Authenticate..

```
json.replace( a.getImage()/*string no ads.getimage()*/, 
  new Base64Encode( "//192.168.1.1//d$//IISFolders//ftp//"+a.getImage() ).encode()/*base64 string image*/ );

/* The encode code - already tested works fine */
public String encode() throws IOException
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[ 2048 ];
    byte[] result = new  byte[ (int) target.length() ];
    int ibytes;
    int counter = 0;

    while( ( ibytes = bis.read(bytes) ) != -1 ) /* Read from buffIn */
    {
        System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, result, counter, ibytes);
        counter += ibytes;
    }

    return new String( Base64.encodeBase64( result ) );
}
```

When I run the code the application couldn't find the file... throwing `java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\192.168.1.1\d$\IISFolders\ftp\teste.png` and (Username and/or password are wrong)...

How could I access this directory and his files?

Comment: You have to user `URL` to point a network location.

Comment: Exactally like you said! Hard to understand alone :S
I was anticipating use relative path to better comprehension...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
FTPClient f = new FTPClient();
f.connect("//192.168.1.1//d$//IISFolders//ftp//");
f.login("foo", "bar");
InputStream is = retrieveFileStream(a.getImage());
...
```

look here for more information:[FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)

Comment: You was thinking in avoid this procedure... but if I don't have other way... I will try!
Thank you for your patience!

Comment: java.net.UnknownHostException: \\192.168.1.1\d$\IISFolders\ftp\
 at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
 at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)

Can you help me??

Comment: Problem solved! Basically, I use my ftp available from IIS.
I was trying use the network relative path, but what the FTPClient from Apache receive is the path from FTP available.
In my case was my server ip 192.168.1.1!